# Android NDK code (jni interface)

Tags: java, c++, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to compile a jni code and generate shared library file. But when I am compiling my code using ndk following error is displayed.

```
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : packtHAL <= jni_wrapper.c
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : packtHAL <= gpio.c
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : packtHAL <= fram.c
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : packtHAL <= bmp183.c
[armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libpacktHAL.so
[armeabi] Install        : libpacktHAL.so => libs/armeabi/libpacktHAL.so
install: cannot stat ‘/home/ankur/Dev/gsoc/demoapps-bbbandroid/app01-gpio/obj/local/armeabi/libpacktHAL.so’: No such file or directory
```

make: *** [/home/ankur/Dev/gsoc/demoapps-bbbandroid/app01-gpio/libs/armeabi/libpacktHAL.so] Error 1

I am using following Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_MODULE := packtHAL
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := jni_wrapper.c gpio.c fram.c bmp183.c
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: "A cannot stat error" means the file or directory does not exist - or you do not have the correct permissions.

Does the /home/ankur/Dev/gsoc/demoapps-bbbandroid/app01-gpio/obj/local/armeabi/ path exist?

Comment: it seems that spidev.h was missing in library file so ndk was not able to compile the code. so I had to copy it in android-ndk/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/include/linux/spi/